# How do I create a Google Form where the user can upload a CSV?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to create a Google Form where the user can upload a CSV and each line in the CSV populates a spreadsheet.

Is there any way to do this in Google Sheets?

Comment: Forms are normally for manual text entry, not for parsing uploaded CSV.  Google Form certainly can't do that. You can make a spreadsheet editable, which would allow users to insert sheets by uploading their CSV.  But this is somewhat different in that users would see each others' uploads; something you probably don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You could tell the user to upload their CSV to Dropbox (or similar) and to share it, and to enter link to their shared file into your Google Form.

Then have a script behind the Form which picks up the link, opens the file and copies/pastes the data into a spreadsheet of yours.

Now, I'm not the person to write this script.   And it does depend on your users being smart enough to upload the file and share it.  But in concept this should work.